# java how to catch an exception in main?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, program-entry-point

I need to read lines from an input path (file).
to do so the main calls a class that uses BufferedReader , it iterates over each line and adds it to an Array.
the problem is: 
I want to catch all exceptions thrown from the method in the class in the main.

```
    public static void main (String[] args){
    if (args.length != 2){
        System.err.print("ERROR");
        return;
    }
    MyFileScript.sourceDir = args[SOURCE_DIR_INDEX];
    MyFileScript.commandFile = args[COMMAND_INDEX];
    try (FileReader file = new FileReader(MyFileScript.commandFile);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file)){

        fileParsing = new CommandFileParser(reader);
        sectionList = fileParsing.parseFile();

    }catch (FileNotFoundException error){
        System.err.print(ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return;
    }catch(IOException error){
        System.err.print(ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return;
    }catch(ErrorException error){
        System.err.print(error.getMessage());
        return;
    }
}


public class CommandFileParser {

public CommandFileParser (BufferedReader reader){
    this.reader = reader;
}

/**
 * read all lines from a file.
 * 
 * @return a string array containing all file lines
 */
public String[] readFileLines(){

    ArrayList<String> fileLines = new ArrayList<String>();

    String textLine;
    while ((textLine = this.reader.readLine()) != null){
        fileLines.add(textLine);
    }
    String[] allFileLines = new String[fileLines.size()];
    fileLines.toArray(allFileLines);
    return allFileLines;
}
```

in the while loop I get a compilation error for unhandling the IOException.

How can I catch all exceptions in main,
and so the class takes only one string argument?

Comment: What about just catch(Exception)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `readFileLines` method is lacking a throws clause.

```
public String[] readFileLines() throws IOException {
```